# Fill a dummy matrix with help of dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, adjacency-matrix

I want to use dictionary keys to get to their respective values and then use these values to reference certain elements in my 2D Array.

I do have a 2d-dummy matrix which I create like this:

```
self.matrix = [[0] * self.length] * self.length
```

which creates an N x N matrix depending on the length

I also have a sorted list of nodes that have names (=keys) and I want to map these names to indices (=values) 0..N

```
self.data = dict(zip(self.nodes, self.index_array))
```

It all works perfectly fine up until I try to fill my dummy adjacency matrix with "1" for Ni is connected to Nj.
"edges" is a list of tuples: edges = [("u1","v1"),("u1","v2"),...,("ui","uj")]

```
for row in edges:
    self.matrix[self.data[row[0]]][self.data[row[1]]] = 1
```

Now when I run the method above, I get a matrix that is full of ones when there should only be ones for every connection between node u and node v

---

I tried modelling this problem in a smaller manner and here it worked perfectly! I don't know what's going on.

```
a = {"3": 0, "4": 1, "5": 2}
edges = [("3", "5"), ("4", "3"), ("5", "3")]
nodes = ["3", "4", "5"]
index = [0, 1, 2]

data = dict(zip(nodes, index))

matrix = [[0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0]]

for row in edges:
    matrix[data[row[0]]][data[row[1]]] = 1

print(a)
print(data)
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not create the matrix correctly:

```
self.matrix = [[0] * self.length] * self.length
```

Use:

```
self.matrix = [[0] * self.length for _ in range(self.length)]
```

The reason is multiplying a list creates multiples of the references in the list, so every row is a reference to the *same* list in your original code.

Here's an example of the difference:

```
>>> A = [[0] * 3] * 3
>>> A
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> A [0][0] = 1
>>> A
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Note above how *all three rows* changed.  This is due to each row containing a copy of the *same* list:

```
>>> A = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
>>> A
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> A[0][0] = 1
>>> A
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Now a new row of three zeroes is created for each row.  Changing one element in a row doesn't change all the rows.

Note that `[0] * 3` also duplicates the references to the integer zero as well.  Being an immutable object this isn't a problem, but if you have a mutable object you don't want three copies.  You would use `[mutable_obj() for _ in range(3)]` to create 3 *different* objects, so if you edit one the others don't change.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! I'm new to programming and I dont know what to fill in the blank space in your list comprehension expression. Choosing an arbitrary variable apparently doesn't do the Job. Sorry to bother you

Comment: `_` *is* a variable name.  It is a common Python convention indicating the variable is just a placeholder and isn't used for anything else.  You can put any variable name there.  I'll add an example of *why* it makes a difference with your original code.

Comment: @ABF Also, I did have a typo in the original...too many square brackets.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I'm pleased to have met you!

Answer (score 1):

By using the `*` operator on a list of sublists you're repeating the same references to the sublists, so any change made to a sublist will be reflected on all other items holding the same reference to the sublist.

You can initialize `self.matrix` with a list comprehension instead:

```
self.matrix = [[0] * self.length] for _ in range(self.length)]
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! I'm new to programming and I dont know what to fill in the blank space in your list comprehension expression. Choosing an arbitrary variable apparently doesn't do the Job. Sorry to bother you